# Can't set font-weight on the :after pseudo-element used on <input> elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

So, i've got a custom style on an input element, and I want to place some text on the input with the use of `:after`.

The problem i'm running into is that i cannot seem to change the font-weight on the `:after` element, this problem only occurs with the combination of `input` and `:after` elements.

**CSS**

```css
input[type="checkbox"] { /* enable styling of the checkbox ! */
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input { /* set up some basic styles.... */
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:grey;
}

input:after { /* and we create the :after element */
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:100; /* THIS DOESN'T WORK FOR SOME REASON */
    content: "This should be thin"; /* some text */
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/xQVfL/1/

**TESTED ON**

Chrome for mac (latest)

**QUESTION**

Why can't I set font-weight on the `:after` element set on an `input` element?

Comment: Seems to work for me.. 700 makes it bold.. and 100 makes it thin

Comment: I'm using chrome (mac) and it doesn't work

Comment: 100 basically means normal weight.. does 700 make it bold for you? look here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_font-weight&preval=900

Comment: I noticed that the content doesn't show up in Firefox, but does in Chrome. The text or the gray background both do not work in FF.

Comment: @Phorden The grey background work's fine for me, it's just the font-weight that isnt working

Comment: @koningdavid I was just pointing it out in case you were worried about browser compatibility.

Comment: @Phorden Yeah I just noticed that it's really messed up in firefox, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS :after pseudo element on INPUT field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered here. It seems :after was intended for appending to container tags only. [Can I use the :after pseudo-element on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)

Comment: Well... that sucks. Gonna wait a little longer, maybe someone comes up with a workaround, else ill accept you answer.